# How should I connect PVC plumbing for two sinks to old cast iron stack with two threaded tees?

Tags: plumbing

[image]

Hello community,

So I have two sinks going to the one cast iron main line. Should I cut the main line and add a new single line to both sinks using no hubs? Is there a good way to just tie to the two cast iron fittings with pvc? (I am unsure if the threads are good, 60s home).

Thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: what is the problem you are trying solve? why do you want to change the current set up?

Answer (score 1):

I'm keen to remove cast iron wherever it's practical to do so. In my experience, cast iron older than about 40 years can really get crudded up and slow. That said, removing sections of a stack can be challenging--you have to fit between nearly immobile sections and you have to support the stack while you work, or you have to replace everything going upward all at once.

I'd see if you can get a nipple threaded into the upper hub just as we see in the lower one, using thread paste, and leave the lower one in place. Connect your new PVC to both nipples with [shielded no-hub couplings](https://www.fernco.com/plumbing/shielded-couplings/no-hub-couplings). Be sure to bore out any corrosion in the cast iron hubs to the inner diameter of the nipples.

If those hubs are 1-1/2" or larger, that may be enough for two sinks. You could just plug the upper one and connect to the lower nipple.

Comment: There basically isn’t threads to thread a nipple on the top hub so that is the real “problem”. And since the joint turns right at the mainline to the closer sink there isn’t enough pipe to use a no-hub coupling, from what I know (unless you can place the coupling over the knuckle). Is there something else that can go where the nipple should thread in that does the same job?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use something lke this https://www.grainger.com/product/4WHU7?cm_mmc=PPC:+Google+PLA&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!166588805278!!!s!82128167277!&ef_id=VMqErAAAALEIyV6c:20180403191528:s If there's some obstructions a zoomed out picture would help. Is there a piece of broken pipe in the top hub?

Comment: I added an image to the original post of the corroded threads

Comment: I can't tell what threads remain from that photo. You need to brush it clean. There may be adequate threads under the corrosion (and appears to be at the face of the hub). Since it's a drain you don't need pressure resistance.

Comment: I don't understand your concern about the use of a no-hub. If you removed everything upstream from the nipple there appears to be plenty of room.